# Multiple values using GET method in my template? with django

Tags: python, django, templates, get, paginator

I am trying to send info using GET method and the django paginator.
I am using buttons to send the request and on my views display the corresponding list, that works fine. However, the problem is when I change page to page=2 or whatever, the url is replaced.
For example: you click the button A and the url should appear webpa.com/expedient?letter=A and when you clic next page, it is replaced webpa.com/expedient?page=2 instead of webpa.com/expedient?page=2&letter=A

My template is as follows:

```
<form action="expedient" method="GET">
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="A">A</button>
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="B">B</button>
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="C">C</button>
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="G">G</button>
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="L">L</button>
<button type="submit" name="letter" value="N">N</button>
</form>
```

and the paginator also in the same template is:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
          <nav aria-label="Paginador de portafolio">
            <ul class="pagination">
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_previous %} href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"{% else %} href="#" {% endif %}>Anterior</a></li>
              {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_next %} href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" {% else %} href="#" {% endif %}>Siguiente</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        {% endif %}
```

How can I send the value of the letter in the form and the page number?

I forgot to add the views code, I used a class:

```
class ExpedientView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'portfolios'
    template_name = 'dashboard-admin/portfoliorecords.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Portfolio.objects.filter(moneybox__isnull=True).order_by('owner__last_name')
        letter = self.request.GET.get('letter', None)
        if letter:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__last_name__istartswith=letter)
        return queryset
```

I think I might need to add the letter received from the template and add it to the queryset or another variable perhaps? and return it to the template in the paginator code, something like:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
              <nav aria-label="Paginador de portafolio">
                <ul class="pagination">
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_previous %} href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&letter={{ letter. }}"{% else %} href="#" {% endif %}>Anterior</a></li>
                  {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a></li>
                  {% endfor %}
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_next %} href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&letter={{ letter. }}" {% else %} href="#" {% endif %}>Siguiente</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume as per your code user first click one of the button A, B, C...
you get the value of the button in the request.GET in your views.py
and next when you want to use the value of the button you need to send the value in the context of the template

```py
context = {
   'letter' : 'A',
    ....
}
```

and in your templates you need add like this

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ num }}&letter={{ letter }}">{{num}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the views code. I should call the letter sent by GET method and add it to the class context so I can use it as you said with &letter={{ letter }}

Comment: Yes like that you can send in context and use in HTML template as I wrote in my answer